# Matching lists to dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matching

I have a dataframe of people with Age as a column. I would like to match this age to a group, i.e. Baby=0-2 years old, Child=3-12 years old, Young=13-18 years old, Young Adult=19-30 years old, Adult=31-50 years old, Senior Adult=51-65 years old.

I created the lists that define these year groups, e.g. `Adult=list(range(31,51))` etc.
How do I match the name of the list 'Adult' to the dataframe by creating a new column?

Small input: the dataframe is made up of three columns: df['Name'], df['Country'], df['Age'].

```
Name    Country  Age
Anthony France   15
Albert  Belgium  54
.
.
.
Zahra   Tunisia  14
```

So I need to match the age column with lists that I already have. The output should look like:

```
Name    Country  Age  Group
Anthony France   15   Young
Albert  Belgium  54   Adult
.
.
.
Zahra   Tunisia  14   Young
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add a sample input, as well as the expected output to your question (**as text**)?

Comment: The `RangeDict` datastructure from the [`python-ranges`](https://pypi.org/project/python-ranges/) module might be what you're looking for here, though without you fully stating the problem and giving examples, I can't be sure

Comment: Is age a float? If not, is a 2 years old a baby or a child?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that using `pd.cut`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"person_id": range(25), "age": np.random.randint(0, 100, 25)})
print(df.head(10))
==>
   person_id  age
0          0   30
1          1   42
2          2   78
3          3    2
4          4   44
5          5   43
6          6   92
7          7    3
8          8   13
9          9   76

df["group"] = pd.cut(df.age, [0, 18, 50, 100], labels=["child", "adult", "senior"])
print(df.head(10))
==>
   person_id  age   group
0          0   30   adult
1          1   42   adult
2          2   78  senior
3          3    2   child
4          4   44   adult
5          5   43   adult
6          6   92  senior
7          7    3   child
8          8   13   child
9          9   76  senior
```

---

Per your question, if you have a few lists (like the ones below), and would like to convert use them for 'binning', you can do:

```
# for example, these are the lists
Adult = list(range(18,50))
Child = list(range(0, 18))
Senior = list(range(50, 100))

# Creating bins out of the lists. 
bins = [min(l) for l in [Child, Adult, Senior]]
bins.append(max([max(l) for l in [Child, Adult, Senior]]))
labels = ["Child", "Adult", "Senior"]

# using the bins: 
df["group"] = pd.cut(df.age, bins, labels=labels)
```

Comment: is there a way to match based on existing lists? so I'm matching the 'Age' column to the name of the list that contains those values

Comment: Are these lists in different variables (e.g. adults.= list (...) children = list( ...) or in some structure that contains the string corresponding to each age group (e.g a dict)?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC I would go with `np.select`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [3, 20, 40]})
condlist = [df.Age.between(0,2),
            df.Age.between(3,12),
            df.Age.between(13,18),
            df.Age.between(19,30),
            df.Age.between(31,50),
            df.Age.between(51,65)]

choicelist = ['Baby', 'Child', 'Young',
           'Young Adult', 'Adult', 'Senior Adult']

df['Adult'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

**Output:**

```
   Age        Adult
0    3        Child
1   20  Young Adult
2   40        Adult
```

Comment: I already have the lists. Is there any way to match the values in "age" to the lists names'? Something like an If statement or VLOOKUP between a list and a dataframe column.

Comment: Lists are way less eficient than using `between` afaik. There's ways but they're not necessarily better. Also, list names mean nothing. If you really want to use lists they should be inside a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

To make things more clear for beginners, you can **define a function** that will return the age group of each person accordingly, then **use [`pandas.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply that function** to our `'Group'` column:

```
import pandas as pd

def age(row):
    a = row['Age']
    if 0 < a <= 2:
        return 'Baby'
    elif 2 < a <= 12:
        return 'Child'
    elif 12 < a <= 18:
        return 'Young'
    elif 18 < a <= 30:
        return 'Young Adult'
    elif 30 < a <= 50:
        return 'Adult'
    elif 50 < a <= 65:
        return 'Senior Adult'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anthony','Albert','Zahra'],
                   'Country':['France','Belgium','Tunisia'],
                   'Age':[15,54,14]})

df['Group'] = df.apply(age, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Name  Country  Age         Group
0  Anthony   France   15         Young
1   Albert  Belgium   54  Senior Adult
2    Zahra  Tunisia   14         Young
```